# Is there a way to change my domain names ip address to godaddy server

Tags: web-hosting

I have a domain name with hosting that I bought from another provider and now I have godaddy gen4 dedicated server account. so I want to change the server ip of that domain to my godaddy account. I know I have an option to transfer domain. please help me if I can do it in another way.

Answer (score 3):

If you wish to just point your domain to Godaddy gen4 dedicated server, you will have to change A record IP in the DNS zone of your domain.

If you wish to change your domain nameservers IP,  first you will have to create DNS zone on  Godaddy gen4 dedicated server, after that you need to change nameserver IP at Domain registrar.

Please note that DNS records May take 12-24 hours to propagate globally.

Let me know if you have any questions.